# Android: Back button causing WebView to look for wrong asset

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

In my Android app, I start a new Activity by overriding the URL loading of a WebView that loads a local html file from assets. When I click the back button on the Android device to get back to the Activity with the WebView, the WebView now displays the message "Web page not available" with a reference to previous Activity as the "Web page" it's trying to load, e.g. *file:///android_asset/com.example.myproject.BackButtonActivity* instead of *file:///android_asset/example.html*

The WebView is set up using the following code in the Activity's onCreate method:

```
this.webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
this.webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/example.html");

WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.contains("start.back.button.activity")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), BackButtonActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return false;
        }

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
};

this.webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
```

When the Activity containing the WebView is first shown everything displays correctly. I can click the link and the new Activity is started. However, when I click the devices back button, the WebView looks for an asset with the name of the previous Activity's class name, not the original file, and fails to load properly.

Any ideas on why this is occurring and any potential fixes would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the logcat output from when the back button is pressed to when the Activity containing the WebView is presented:

```
02-28 02:58:39.218    9291-9317/com.example.myproject V/webcore﹕ 230 arg1=1 arg2=0 obj=null
02-28 02:58:39.231    9291-9317/com.example.myproject V/webcore﹕ 230 arg1=0 arg2=0 obj=null
02-28 02:58:39.243    9291-9291/com.example.myproject D/GraphicBuffer﹕ create handle(0x61230760) (w:480, h:782, f:1)
02-28 02:58:39.245    9291-9291/com.example.myproject D/GraphicBuffer﹕ close handle(0x61230760) (w:480 h:782 f:1)
02-28 02:58:39.246    9291-9291/com.example.myproject D/GraphicBuffer﹕ create handle(0x61230760) (w:480, h:782, f:1)
02-28 02:58:39.248    9291-9317/com.example.myproject V/webcore﹕ SET_ACTIVE arg1=1 arg2=0 obj=null
02-28 02:58:39.248    9291-9291/com.example.myproject V/InputMethodManager﹕ onWindowFocus: android.webkit.WebView{41d02530 VFEDHVCL .F....ID 0,0-480,672 #7f0d001f app:id/activity_mywebview} softInputMode=16 first=true flags=#1810100
02-28 02:58:39.248    9291-9291/com.example.myproject D/webview﹕ onCreateInputConnection
02-28 02:58:39.248    9291-9291/com.example.myproject D/WebViewInputConnection﹕ resetBatchLevel mBatchLevel = 0
02-28 02:58:39.248    9291-9291/com.example.myproject V/InputMethodManager﹕ START INPUT: android.webkit.WebView{41d02530 VFEDHVCL .F....ID 0,0-480,672 #7f0d001f app:id/activity_mywebview} ic=android.webkit.WebViewClassic$WebViewInputConnection@41d2e148 tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@41d1fb68 controlFlags=#105
02-28 02:58:39.251    9291-9291/com.example.myproject V/InputMethodManager﹕ Starting input: Bind result=InputBindResult{com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy@41d1fc68 com.htc.sense.ime/.HTCIMEService #2861}
02-28 02:58:39.267    9291-9325/com.example.myproject I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5eb9d4e0) fps:1.52, dur:12462.08, max:12084.30, min:5.31
02-28 02:58:39.267    9291-9325/com.example.myproject I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [STC::queueBuffer] this:0x5eb9d4e0, api:2, last queue time elapsed:12084.30
02-28 02:58:39.267    9291-9325/com.example.myproject I/BufferQueue﹕ [unnamed-9291-0](this:0x5eb9c5f0,api:2) [queue] fps:1.52, dur:12461.71, max:12084.44, min:5.32
02-28 02:58:39.269    9291-9291/com.example.myproject I/BufferQueue﹕ [unnamed-9291-0](this:0x5eb9c5f0,api:2) [release] fps:1.60, dur:12467.44, max:12075.28, min:6.18
02-28 02:58:39.288    9291-9291/com.example.myproject D/GraphicBuffer﹕ create handle(0x5e3d6d70) (w:480, h:782, f:1)
02-28 02:58:39.289    9291-9291/com.example.myproject D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 0)
02-28 02:58:39.289    9291-9291/com.example.myproject D/GraphicBuffer﹕ close handle(0x5ed66d70) (w:480 h:782 f:1)
02-28 02:58:39.290    9291-9291/com.example.myproject D/GraphicBuffer﹕ close handle(0x5e3d6d70) (w:480 h:782 f:1)
02-28 02:58:39.296    9291-9291/com.example.myproject D/GraphicBuffer﹕ create handle(0x5f38db68) (w:480, h:782, f:1)
02-28 02:58:39.604    9291-9291/com.example.myproject D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 0)
02-28 02:58:40.330    9291-9325/com.example.myproject I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5eb9d4e0) fps:3.76, dur:1063.85, max:1019.87, min:6.87
02-28 02:58:40.330    9291-9325/com.example.myproject I/BufferQueue﹕ [unnamed-9291-0](this:0x5eb9c5f0,api:2) [queue] fps:3.76, dur:1063.79, max:1019.96, min:6.88
02-28 02:58:40.436    9291-9291/com.example.myproject D/GraphicBuffer﹕ create handle(0x5e3d5fd0) (w:480, h:782, f:1)
02-28 02:58:40.441    9291-9291/com.example.myproject I/BufferQueue﹕ [unnamed-9291-0](this:0x5eb9c5f0,api:2) [release] fps:3.41, dur:1171.79, max:1126.83, min:6.62
02-28 02:58:40.445    9291-9291/com.example.myproject I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5ed2bbc8) fps:1.68, dur:1188.10, max:1114.11, min:73.99
02-28 02:58:40.453    9291-9291/com.example.myproject D/GraphicBuffer﹕ create handle(0x5ed72be8) (w:480, h:782, f:1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the return statements of your `WebViewClient`:

```
WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.contains("start.back.button.activity")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), BackButtonActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;      // <--- Switch to true
        }
        //view.loadUrl(url);  // <--- You don't need this line when returning false
        return false;         // <--- Switch to false
    }
};
```

From the [docs](http://file:///E:/AndroidSDK/docs/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)):

> Returns true if the host application wants to handle the key event itself, otherwise return false

Comment: Well that was easy. Thanks!